# Use have_comments() for current post instead of last post in loop

Tags: loop, comments

I've a page that uses a loop over posts. Within the loop, I use `$query->the_post();` and it works fine.

However, when I'm finished looping, `the_post()` is still set to the last post in my loop. So when I use `have_comments()`, I get the comments for that post instead of the comments for the current page -which is what I need. Does that make any sense?

What's the right way to solve this? `have_comments()` does not take any argument such as the ID of the current page.

Comment: please post the full code of the template; it might not contain any `wp_reset_postdata()` or so at the end ...

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to *rewind*, with the `rewind_posts()` method, to reset `$current_post` and `$post` [[docs]](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). There's also `rewind_comments()` to reset `$current_comment` and `$comment` (the current comment ID property)  [[src]](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0b0c754563d4b595fca0cdafb4d8ac52a32b744b/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3342).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. Does the `rewind_posts()` method basically come down to querying the current page twice (before and after my loop)?

Comment: Calling the `rewind_posts()` method will not run another db query. (similar to rewind for iterators, but `WP_Query` doesn't implement such an interface, ... yet ;-)